# Python Socket :socket connection refused

Tags: python, django, sockets

env:linux + python3 + rornado

When i run client.py,he suggested that my connection was rejected, for a few ports,Using the 127.0.0.1:7233,The server does not have any response, but the client prompts to refuse to connect,Who can tell me why?

server.py

```
# coding:utf8

import socket
import time
import threading


# accept conn
def get_hart(host, port):
    global clien_list
    print('begin get_hart')
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(5)
    print(clien_list)

    while True:
        try:
            clien, address = s.accept()
            try:
                clien_data = clien.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
                if clien_data == str(0):
                    clien_id = clien_reg()
                    clien.send(str(clien_id))
                    print(clien_list)
                else:
                    clien_list[int(clien_data)]['time'] = time.time()
                    # print clien_data
            except:
                print('send fail！')
            clien.close()
        except:
            print("accept fail!")
            continue


# client reg
def clien_reg():
    global clien_list
    tim = str(time.time() / 100).split('.')
    id = int(tim[1])
    clien_list[id] = {"time": time.time(), "state": 0}
    return id


# client dict
def check_hart(clien_list, delay, lost_time):
    while True:
        for id in clien_list:
            if abs(clien_list[id]['time'] - time.time()) > lost_time:
                clien_list[id]['state'] = 0
                del clien_list[id]  # del offline client
                break  # err
            else:
                clien_list[id]['state'] = 1
        print(clien_list)
        time.sleep(delay)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 7233
    global clien_list  # Dict: client info
    clien_list = {}
    lost_time = 30  # timeout
    print('begin threading')
    try:
        threading.Thread(target=get_hart,args=(host,port,),name='getHart')
        threading.Thread(target=check_hart,args=(clien_list, 5, lost_time,))
    except Exception as e:
        print("thread error!"+e)

    while 1:
        pass
    print('e')
```

client.py

```
# coding:utf8

import socket
import time


# sent pkg
def send_hart(host, port, delay):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print(host,port)
    global clien_id
    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
        s.send(clien_id)
        if clien_id == 0:
            try:
                to_clien_id = s.recv(1024)
                clien_id = to_clien_id
            except:
                print('send fail！')
            print(to_clien_id)  # test id
        time.sleep(delay)
    except Exception as e:
        print('connect fail!:'+e)
        time.sleep(delay)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 7233
    global clien_id
    clien_id = 0  # client reg id
    while True:
        send_hart(host, port, 5)
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/XPlan/socket_test/client.py", line 13, in send_hart
    s.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/XPlan/socket_test/client.py", line 34, in <module>
    send_hart(host, port, 5)
  File "/home/ubuntu/XPlan/socket_test/client.py", line 24, in send_hart
    print('connect fail!:'+e)
TypeError: Can't convert 'ConnectionRefusedError' object to str implicitly

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
print('connect fail!:'+e)
```

to

```
print('connect fail!:'+str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the problem, 
first, thread need start () function to start, 
the second, Python3, send () function to accept the value of bytes, 
the third, print abnormal need to switch to str type

```
threading.Thread(target=get_hart,args=(host,port,),name='getHart',).start()

print("thread error!"+str(e))
```